# Does this laptop can have 16 GB of RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory, ramdisk

I am planning to buy this laptop: Acer Aspire ES1-572 (UN.GKQSI.003) Core i3 6th Gen - 6006U / 4 GB / 500GB HDD /15.6 inch Led Display / Linux / Midnight Black

How to find out if I can extend this laptop's RAM upto 16GB?

If expandable, which RAM I should buy? Kingston KVR16LS11/4 4GB 1600MHz DDR3L Laptop RAM (or) Kingston 8 GB RAM FOR LAPTOP 1600MHZ PC3L - KVR16LS118 (LOW VOLTAGE).

EDIT: More information on Laptop Memory:

```
memory layout :1 x 4 Gigabyte
expandable memory : 16 GB
ram type :  DDR3
memory slots :  2 DIMM
ram speed : 1600 Mhz
capacity :  4 GB
```

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the question.

Comment: I wanted to confirm. So, I buy this laptop, remove the existing 4 GB RAM, buy two "Kingston 8 GB RAM FOR LAPTOP 1600MHZ PC3L - KVR16LS118 (LOW VOLTAGE)" RAMs and install it?

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-es1-572-357c) lists compatible upgrades and indeed claims a maximum memory of 16 GB, but specifies the model as "Acer Aspire ES1-572 **-357C** ".

```
Maximum Memory:16GB
Slots:2 (2 banks of 1)
*Not to exceed manufacturer supported memory
```

Apparently though, you need to buy two 8-GB modules:

```
Crucial 16GB Kit (2 x 8GB) DDR3L-1600 SODIMM
CT8895927

DDR3 PC3-12800 • CL=11 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC • DDR3-1600 • 1.35V • 1024Meg x 64
• upgrade for Acer Aspire ES1-572-357C system.
```